# Any reasons not to gzip documents delivered via HTTP?

Tags: compression, bandwidth, http-compression

I remember someone telling me that gzipped content is not cached on some browsers?
is this true?

Are there any other reasons why I shouldn't gzip my content (pages, javascript and css files) with htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other reason is it obviously increase CPU load, but whether this is a problem depends on your content type and your traffic.

If you are going to use GZip from with `.htaccess`, be sure to wrap it in a condition whereby it only executed of the mod_gzip module exists, this will make the site / app more portable if moving it to another server.

If you opt to use `.htaccess` GZipped content the browser will receive compressed content if it supports it, or received the normal uncompressed version if it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

If you are delivering mostly .gz files, then obviously you don't want to gzip them. Otherwise it's probably a good idea, especially for cache-able content. I have never heard of caches not working with gzipped content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to handle both GZipped and not gzipped data since IE6 and GZipping do not live together nicely.

Otherwise I cant think of an issue

Answer (score -1):

If you need to stream the content of a page, or want to use `Response.Flush`, then you can't use compression/gzip.